# How to make validations work with @RequestParam

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate-validator

Given `Spring Boot 2.6.3`, `Hibernate validator 6.2.0.Final`, after running the code below:

```
import org.springframework.validation.annotation.Validated;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;
import javax.validation.constraints.Min;

@RestController
@Validated
public class TestController {
    @GetMapping("/test")
    public Integer test( @Min(10) @RequestParam Integer val) {
        return val;
    }
}
```

If I call http://localhost:8080/test?val=0 , it returns 0 and it seems it ignores `@Min(10)` part.

Does anybody know whether it is possible to validate `@RequestParam` parameters?

Comment: What version of Spring Boot are you using? Do you’ve Hibernate validator on classpath, and if yes, what version?

Comment: I just created the Spring Boot project, with version 2.6.3. Hibernate validator is 6.2.0.Final.

Comment: [Validating RequestParams and PathVariables in Spring MVC](https://sadique.io/blog/2015/12/05/validating-requestparams-and-pathvariables-in-spring-mvc/)

Comment: Spring Boot no longer adds `spring-boot-starter-validation`, did you add it to your build file?

Comment: Yes, I included `spring-boot-starter-validation`.

Comment: I tried the solution provided in @LeiYang recommandation, and it simply ignores the validation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I generated a Spring project from https://start.spring.io/ as shown below:

[image]

I then added the controller code in your question, and an integration test as below:

```
class DemoApplicationTests {
    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Test
    void testGoodInput() throws Exception {
        mockMvc
                .perform(MockMvcRequestBuilders.get("/test?val=10"))
                .andExpect(MockMvcResultMatchers.status().isOk());
    }

    @Test
    void testBadInput() {
        Throwable ex = catchThrowable(() -> mockMvc
                .perform(MockMvcRequestBuilders.get("/test?val=0"))
                .andReturn());
        var cause = getViolationExceptionFromCause(ex);
        assertThat(cause)
                .isInstanceOf(ConstraintViolationException.class);
    }

    private ConstraintViolationException getViolationExceptionFromCause(Throwable ex) {
        if (ex == null || ex instanceof ConstraintViolationException) {
            return (ConstraintViolationException) ex;
        }
        return getViolationExceptionFromCause(ex.getCause());
    }
}
```

This works as expected, `val=0` throws a `ConstraintViolationException`. It's your turn to prove otherwise.

Comment: so you mean OP's code is working, right?

Comment: @LeiYang No, I don't mean OP's code is working. I mean my code is working using the information provided by OP, so it's reasonable to say that OP hasn't given us all the information needed to debug the problem.

Comment: @AbhijitSarkar You are right, for a blank project it works. I have absolutely no idea what information should I provide, but I agree there must be something else going on.